# Sending HTTP POST to Kitura works wrong on Bluemix

Tags: swift, server, ibm-cloud, kitura

I created a simple REST on Kitura. When I run it on your Mac, it works fine. `GET / POST / PUT / DELETE` are executed. When I run it on bluemix, `GET` method works correctly, but the `POST` is wrong. In response to the `POST` I should return `JSON` to create an object and returns a response with the text "unknown" in the body. Then, at my request any returns "unknown". No errors in the logs there. What could it be?

Kitura version 0.15.6, swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-05-03-a

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on Linux? Can you use the Docker or Vagrant environments on the Mac to speed up the process? This information will help us determine if the issue is specifically Bluemix-related or with Kitura on Linux, which happens to be hosted on Bluemix. Also, can you provide a code snippet? Note: I was asked to post these comments for someone that does not have enough reputation points to post a comment.

Comment: Of course, [that my project](https://mega.nz/#!vYNEwRwQ!l3rylAZz2sYOUZfvXuZKOllaDZuv3W4QyGnW_wzyHm0). I have found that the problem is not in the `POST` request and its processing. The problem somewhere in SwiftyJSON. App.swift:39 `response.status(HTTPStatusCode.OK).send(json: json)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the Linux implementation of SwiftyJSON that incorrectly marked UInts as invalid.

I fixed this and pushed a new version: 7.0.4

This will now work once you update your dependencies.

Comment: Wow, that is a service)) now works as expected. Thank you so much!